# System.Web.UI.Timer Refreshes Page when Enabled

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

During the page_load, I disable the timer. When I pressed Button1, I enable the timer, but the page refreshes. Therefore, it never reaches the timer_tick1. I need to show a popup after a certain amount of time a button is clicked. How do I prevent the refresh from happening?

Alerts Class

```
public static class Alert
{
    public static void Show(string message, Page page)
    {   

        // replaces the quotations to follow the script syntax
        // quotations are interpretated as \\' in script code
        string cleanMessage = message.Replace("'", "\\'");

        string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('" + cleanMessage + "');</script>";

        // Gets the executing web page
        Page tempPage = page;

        // Checks if the handler is a Page and that the script isn't already on the page

        if (tempPage != null & !tempPage.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("alert"))
        {
            tempPage.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Alert), "alert", script); // this isn't working, but it works on a button click event.
        }
    }
}
```

Page Class

```
public partial class Test1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostback) {
        Timer1.Enabled = false;
        Label2.Text = "Panel refreshed at: " +
          DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(); // Checks if page reloads
        }
    }

    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   // i added a breakpoint here. It doesn't even pass through. 

        Alert.Show("hehehehe", this); //PopUp Shows up. 
        Timer1.Enabled = false; //Cancels Timer
        Label1.Text = "Panel refreshed at: " +
        DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(); // Checks if update panel reloads


    }


    protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer1.Enabled = true; //Starts Timer. It seems to refresh the page. 
    }
}
```

script

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test1" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    Namespace="System.Web.UI" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

<script type="text/javascript">

               function delayer() {
        setTimeout (function () {ShowPopUp()}, 15000); 
    }
    delayer();
</script>
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ScriptManager>
        </div>
        &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="1000" Enabled="true">
                </asp:Timer>
                &nbsp;
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="PanelNotRefreshedYet"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="ShowPopUp();" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you need to execute code on the server side to show the popup?

Comment: @Machinegon I'm using an alert class to show the popup. I need to reuse the class.

Comment: Consider doing more client side. You really don't want a lot of server round trips.

Comment: @CodeMonkeyForHire Sorry, I don't understand. I'm new to this. Can you further elaborate or post a link with a concise article?

Comment: Sure. Use javascript . setTimeout for example if you want a timer. You want to get in the habit if doing as much on the client as possible. Lessens server loads, reduces issues with latency and myriad other reasons. Only use server hits when actually needed. Ideally, you would want your site service based but that gets more advanced. If you go large scale, you will want to consider MVC or some SOA.

Comment: @CodeMonkeyForHire Ok, I added javascript code, but it won't compile because of the semicolon added at the function on the onclick property of button1. Can you tell me what the syntax for semicolon is?

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533703/simple-timer-to-update-label-doesnt-work-on-asp-net?

Comment: @John Saunders Hi, I didn't know how to use this site beforehand so I posted 3 topics, but now I know. How do I delete the other one?

Comment: Don't worry. We'll do it for you.

Comment: @John Saunders Thanks. This site is awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're confused. Timer1 is a server side control. So it will fire on the server side, if you're still processing the page, that is, and will have no effect on the client side. By the time it fires in your code, the page has likely already rendered so you'll see no effect from that Timer1 object's Timer1_Tick event. Since the page has completed rendering, you can't inject new JavaScript, modify the page, or anything like that. Remember that web development is a disconnected thing. You send a request, you get a response. There are no events by nature of the web. There are libraries out there for triggering events and such but I think that's way beyond what you're trying to achieve.

For client side "timer" you need to use JavaScript setTimeout method, which you have verified as working and is the proper way for you to achieve the delay you're looking to implement.

```
setTimeout (function () {ShowPopUp()}, 15000);
```

If you still want to do it in your Alert class, then get rid of Timer1 and have your Alert class inject the timeout in JavaScript:

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Alert.Show("He heee", this);
}
```

And in Alert, change your script to:

```
string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">setTimeout(function() {alert('" + cleanMessage + "');}, 15000);</script>";
```

Comment: I added this code in but it won't compile. I think it's the semicolon. Do you know what the syntax for the semicolon is?                                                                                           <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="ShowPopUp();" />

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it to work. This is way cleaner code. Do you have any suggestions where I can quickly learn javascript?

Comment: Honestly, there is a lot out there to learn. I would suggest starting out with a beginner's book. Then get to learn the tools such as [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), debuggers (Firebug, Chrome and IE debuggers, etc), and libraries such as [JQuery](http://jquery.com/), [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/), [Knockout JS](http://knockoutjs.com/)... There's a lot. :)

Comment: BTW, I really love Knockout JS and used it on my last two projects. Very solid and clean library.

Answer (score 0):

Your button is doing a postback, so yes the page will be refreshed and your Page_Load function will run again. You should test for this using the `IsPostback` property.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostback) {
        Timer1.Enabled = false;
        Label2.Text = "Panel refreshed at: " +
          DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(); // Checks if page reloads
    }
}
```

You might want to look at showing the alert using JavaScript on the page rather than running it server side tho.

Comment: I used an alert class so I don't have to write it on the page and because I need to reuse the alert. Is there a similar method i can use on the page?

Comment: Ok, I fixed it by adding a trigger for the button so it only updates the timer in the update panel.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function showPopup()
     {
       alert("Hey, click something already");
      }

           function delayer() {
            setTimeout (showPopUp, 15000); 
               }
delayer();
</script>
```

Just put your message like this. Probably easier if your logic is simple.

Comment: I really should learn javascript. Do you have any suggestions where I can quickly learn the knowhow's?

Comment: I suggest you pick up a good book. Javascript is a must have in today's web. Learn JQuery , which is a framework built on JavaScript for easier DOM manipulation. Go through a bunch of tutorials, numerous on the web to gain a good understanding. Toy around with jsfiddle.net which is cool for live interaction.